# how to remove dollar sign from jquery-ui slider input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery-ui slider ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps ) where the value of the slider position is displayed in an input box, and change in input box value re-positions the slider index.

js snippet:

```
$("#slider, ").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 4,
    min: 1,
    max: 18,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".slider_input" ).val( "$" + ui.value );

        //$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );
    }


   });


$(".slider_input").change(function () {
    var value = this.value.substring(1);

    $("#slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
});
```

html:

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<input class="slider_input" />
```

But I want to remove the dollar sign from the input . If I use `$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );` instead of `$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );`, then manual change in input box value does not move the slider index position as expected.

How can I remove the dollar sign and make the slider work accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/wm8Dh/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spit function.

```
> "$42.00".split('$')
[ '', '42.00' ]


> "$42.00".substring(1)
'42.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` to remove `$` from the value.

```
   $( ".slider_input" ).val( ui.value.replace("$","") );
```

Comment: no error in console. but the slider index could not be moved.